# finding particular lists in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary like this

```
my_d = {"a": [1, 2, 2, 5, 2],
        "b": [2, 1, 2, 4, 5],
        "c": [7, 2, 2, 6, 2], 
        "d": [7, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
```

I am looking for the keys whose dictionary values contain 2 more than twice. In the example, that would be `"a","c","d"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `count` function in a list comprehension :

```
>>> my_d = {"a":[1,2,2,5,2],"b":[2,1,2,4,5],"c":[7,2,2,6,2], "d":[7,2,2,2,2]}
>>> [i for i,j in my_d.items() if j.count(2)>2]
['a', 'c', 'd']
```

[`my_d.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) give you the list of the items of your dictionary .